# What is a Process Handle?

Tags: windows, process, task-manager, operating-system, process-explorer

What is a process handle and what can we know about a running process through the "handle count" property in a task explorer?

[image]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A process handle is an integer value that identifies a process to Windows.  The Win32 API calls them a HANDLE; handles to windows are called HWND and handles to modules HMODULE.

Threads inside processes have a thread handle, and files and other resources (such as registry keys) have handles also.

The handle count you see in Task Manager is "[the number of object handles in the process's object table](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc958260.aspx)".  In effect, this is the sum of all handles that this process has open.

If you do not release your handle to a resource, other people may not be able to access it - this is why you sometimes cannot delete a file because Windows claims it is in use  (check out [this article on handle leaks and Process Explorer](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/alexexmachina/cleaning-up-handle-leaks-with-process-explorer-14667)).

Also, there is a per-process limit on various handles.  [Here is an example](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2007/07/18/3926581.aspx).

In general, if you are opening handles and not closing them, it is analogous to leaking memory.  You should figure out what is going on and fix it.  There is a good [CodeProject article on handle leaks](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/cdbntsd5.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Handle is an integer value which is used to address an Objects. 
For example:

```
int handle = open( "foo.txt", OTHER_STUFF_HERE );
```

`open()` is System Call returns  a handle, a small, non-negative integer for use in subsequent system calls (read(2), write(2), lseek(2), fcntl(2), etc.).

Windows handles are very similar to Unix file descriptors (FDs).

Comment: The windows `open()` syscall is deprecated - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/open